# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2100 - 2850'

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

How can i solve this problem?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
train = pd.read_csv(r"G:\data_science\input\train.csv")
cat_columns = ['area_type','availability','location','size','society','bath','balcony']
for col in train.columns:
    if col in cat_columns:
        train[col]= train[col].astype('category')
        train[col]= train[col].cat.codes
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, SGDRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
test = pd.read_csv(r"G:\data_science\input\test.csv")
y_train = train['price']
x_train = train.drop('price', axis = 1)
y_test = test['price']
x_test = test.drop('price',axis = 1)

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
prediction = model.predict(x_test)
prediction
```

Comment: It means that you have in a column '2100 - 2850' which is not a float. You should inspect your data first and see which dtypes you have in it

Comment: One of the cells with value `2100-28501` in `train.csv` file, there is a `-` (dash) character. check your file carefully and remove `-`.

Comment: "Solve my problem here's my code" is not a valid question on SO. The problem should be explained so as to hold value for future readers, or this post should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

All your values are read as `string` from the csv file.

Now, somewhere you are trying to convert some values into `float`.

But the value that it has encountered is `'2100 - 2850'`.

Now you cannot convert this value into `float` and that is what the error is saying.

Please check the dataset once and resolve any such garbage value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution!
I have encountered the same thing in Bangalore house price prediction.

```
def preprocess_total_sqft(val):
    try:
        return float(val)
    except:
        if('-' in val):
            values=val.split('-')
            #Taking average  total sqft value if there is a range If you want only one you can take either of one I took average of both the values t my analysis.
            val=float(values[0])+float(values[1])/2
        
    data['total_sqft']=data['total_sqft'].apply(preprocess_total_sqft)
    print(type(data['total_sqft'][0]))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

def preprocess_total_sqft(val):

```
try:

    return float(val)
except:
    if('-' in val):
        values=val.split('-')
        #Taking average  total sqft value if there is a range If you want only one you can take either of one I took average of both the values t my analysis.
```

val=float(values[0])+float(values[1])/2

```
data['total_sqft']=data['total_sqft'].apply(preprocess_total_sqft)
print(type(data['total_sqft'][0]))
```

above code is right but need to change on

val = (float(values[0])+float(values[1]))/2